# CosmosDB nuget package not being available

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

When I read about standard libraries i understand it as it can be used with core and standard (correct me if I am wrong). I have created a Standard library as a data library.

I now want to implement DocumentDB so I added the nuget package:
[image]
So my dependencies looks like this:
[image: Visual Studio Dependcies]

However I am not able to use the nuget package:

[image]

I dont get any errors, so I am guessing it must be the framework target? Any pointers here?

Comment: If it was a problem with the target framework you would get a warning (that yellow rectangle) in the nuget package

Comment: I just added a simple win form project target with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and added same nuget to that project. Then it works. I actually thought .NET standard was prefered because it could target both Core and .NET framework. But as you say I dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the dependencies on the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB package, it is dependent on .NET Framework v4.6.1. While .NET Standard 2.0 allows the loading of packages from .NET Framework it's discouraged as you can run into unexpected errors.

[image]

Instead you can use the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core package or the new v3 package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos as they both target .NET Standard directly so there will be no compatibility issues.